# Passing variables into ng-transclude

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-compile

I am wondering, is it possible to pass an $index param into the ng-transclude? I am trying to focus into the textarea by clicking on the elements in the ng-transclude, triggering a function inside the controller that sees the textarea, but I can't get the right ID.

```
<div
    ng-repeat="locale in $ctrl.enabled">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td flex layout="row" layout-align="start end">
                    <ng-transclude
                        ng-transclude-slot="theExtraMenu">
                    </ng-transclude>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <md-input-container
                        md-no-float="true">
                        <textarea id="{{'textarea'+$index}}">
                        </textarea>
                    </md-input-container>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The AnguarJS $compile service links transcluded content to the parent scope of the component. Since the `$index` property is part of the a child scope of the components scope, it is not available to any transcluded content.

Comment: I can think of three ways for transcluded content to communicate with a component controller. Scope variables is not one of them.

Comment: I'm listening...

Comment: With the `<textarea>` element, contents is bound to a controller with the `ng-model` directive.

Comment: @georgeawg Would you do it in the way that I answered? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the end, I created a parent component that has the locale as an input and transcludes all of the necessary content. Then I require the controller of said component and that's how I see the value of locale.

The reason I didn't go with the scope parent access was that if the hierarchy of the scope changed, it got broken.

Thanks [@georgeawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535245/georgeawg) for inspiration.

EDIT: example -

```
<div ng-repeat="locale in $ctrl.enabled">
 <translated-textarea-menu locale="locale">

  <the-extra-menu>
    <ng-transclude ng-transclude-slot="theExtraMenu"></ng-transclude>
  </the-extra-menu>

 </translated-textarea-menu>
```

The parent component (translated-textarea-menu)

```
component: {
    templateUrl: 'xyz.html',
    bindings: {
        locale: '&',
    },
    transclude: {
        theExtraMenu: '?theExtraMenu'
    },
    controller: TranslatedTextareaMenuController,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
}
```

And then in the transcluded component (the extra menu component)

```
component: {
    templateUrl: 'x.html',
    bindings: {
        variables: '&'
    },
    require: {
        translatedTextareaMenu: '^translatedTextareaMenu'
    },
    controller: TheExtraMenuController,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
}
```

And access it with `this.translatedTextareaMenu.locale`

Directives can `require` the controllers of other directives to enable communication between each other. This can be achieved in a component by providing an object mapping for the `require` property. The object keys specify the property names under which the required controllers (object values) will be bound to the requiring component's controller.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Intercomponent Communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-)

Comment: An example would be helpful.

Comment: There we go @georgeawg

Comment: [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) is the way the [`<textarea>` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/textarea) communicates with the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). And the way the `ngModelController` communicates with the [`<form>` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) and its [ngFormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).